# pygame I can move my character but not greatly

Tags: python, pygame

I am currently making a game with pygame, but when I change direction, I stop and have to press the arrow key again. It doesn't seem like a big problem, but it will get annoying very easily.

This is the code (it's written in the game's loop, so that is not a problem):

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == K_LEFT:
        coordsX = coordsX - 0.1

    elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
        coordsX = coordsX + 0.1

    elif event.key == K_UP:
        coordsY = coordsY - 0.1

    elif event.key == K_DOWN:
        coordsY = coordsY + 0.1

    elif event.key == K_LEFT and event.key == K_UP:
        coordsX = coordsX - 0.1
        coordsY = coordsY - 0.1

    elif event.key == K_LEFT and event.key == K_DOWN:
        coordsX = coordsX - 0.1
        coordsY = coordsY + 0.1

    elif event.key == K_RIGHT and event.key == K_UP:
        coordsX = coordsX + 0.1
        coordsY = coordsY - 0.1

    elif event.key == K_RIGHT and event.key == K_DOWN:
        coordsX = coordsX + 0.1
        coordsY = coordsY + 0.1
```

Comment: Don't act on events directly, but store your x and y speed in variables.

Comment: I think the event fires once when the key is first depressed. There will then be a separate keyup event when the key is released. You will need to store some state so that when the key_down happens, you record "moving left" and when the key is then released, you stop moving left. At the moment, you move left one time when the key is first pressed, but there's nothing in your code that keeps on moving until the key is released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this case, you probably don't care when the keys were pressed or their order, but you do want to know which keys are pressed. So instead, you might want to look at [pygame.key.get_pressed](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed).

The main loop would then look more like this

```
pygame.event.pump()
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[K_LEFT]:
    coordsX -= 0.1
if keys[K_RIGHT]:
    coordsX += 0.1
...
```

Also, skip using elif here and the conditions will take care of themselves.

Answer (score 1):

An example of what I mean in my comment above:

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == K_LEFT:
        moving_left = True
    elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
        moving_right = True
    elif ....

elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
    if event.key == K_LEFT:
        moving_left = False
    elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
        moving_right = False
    elif ....

if moving_left:
    coordsX = coordsX - 0.1
if moving_right:
    coordsX = coordsX + 0.1
if ...
```